# Es posible hacer funcionar un input radio como si fuera un checkbox utilizando localStorage para ocultar el contenido de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Básicamente necesito hacer lo que mencione en el titulo.
Si el input de tipo radio esta marcado que me oculte un tabla, caso contrario si esta desmarcado me muestre el contenido y al actualizar la pagina me guarde el estado del input.

Comment: Creo que no es posible que un _radio_ funcione como _checkbox_, no hay forma de desmarcarlo. Por otra parte, te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta se ajuste a las normas de SOes y tengas posibilidad de obtener una respuesta útil.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede, claro. Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es que dependiendo de la selección en los controles de un formulario hay contenido que aparece o desaparece, tal vez para hacer formularios con preguntas dependientes.

El problema es que quieres hacerlo con jQuery o trabajando sobre el mismo DOM, es ineficiente tener que llevar tú mismo la cuenta del estado de los objetos. Podrías declarar que al pinchar en la opción indicada, se hace visible la tabla. Al pinchar en otra opción, se oculta. Eso equivale a decir que estás vigilando todos los clicks en el radio-group, y luego tienes que revisar qué radio quedó activo para decidir si toca mostrar u ocultar la tabla.

Te aconsejo buscar alguna librería con data-binding tal que simplemente puedas definir declarativamente "esta tabla se muestra cuando el checkbox tiene valor "con".

Este ejemplo usa AlpineJS. Como Vue pero para cosas bien concretas..

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid" x-data="{value:'sin'}">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="con_o_sin_tabla" id="sin" x-bind:checked="value=='sin'" @click="value='sin'">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="sin">
    Sin tabla, gracias
  </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="con_o_sin_tabla" id="con" x-bind:checked="value=='con'" @click="value='con'">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="con">
    Con tabla por favor
  </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <table x-show.transition="value=='con'" class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentar simular el comportamiento de un `checkbox` en un `radiobutton` no es posible con `javascript`.
Te dejo un ejemplo en donde intento con la función `prop()` añadirle la propiedad `checked` a la etiqueta html, pero simplemente no funciona; de igual manera hice el intento con `attr()`, pero inspeccionando con la herramienta de desarrollador del navegador me pude observar que la función en ningún momento lo hizo.
El codigo funciona y esconde la sección deseada pero no logra marcar el `radio button` como seleccionado.

Sin embargo hay otra forma de simular ese comportamiento.
Te dejo los dos ejemplos.

Primer ejemplo donde intento simular el comportamiento con `javascript` directamente en el `radio button` y también un ejemplo de como sería con un `checkbox`

```js
// creo una variable tipo buleana para llevar el control del check o unchecked
var flag = false;
//query selector para agregarle el evento onClick al radio button
$('#rb').on('click', function(event){
  
  //event.preventDefalut(); evita el comportamiento del radiobutton
  //de seleccionarse en el momento que hacemos click en este
  //hice el intento con y sin el eventDefault
  event.preventDefault();
  if ( flag === false ){
    flag = true;
    //intento quitarle el attributo 'checked' al radiobutton
    $('#rb').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#texto').hide();
  }else{
    flag = false;
    //intento añadirle el attributo 'checked' al radiobutton
    //hice el intento con .prop('checked'), .prop('checked', true), .attr('checked',true)
    $('#rb').attr('checked');
    $('#texto').show();
  }
});
//query selector para agregarle el evento onClick al checkbox
$('#cb').on('click', function(event){
  //valido si está seleccionado o no
  if ( $('#cb').prop('checked') ){
    //escondo el párrafo con id 'texto'
    $('#texto').hide();
  }else{
    //muestro el párrafo con id 'texto'
    $('#texto').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="rb">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">

<p id="texto">texto a esconder</p>
```

La única forma que se me ocurra para que puedas simular ese comportamiento es que pongas el `radio button` dentro de un `div`

```js
//la misma variable para llevar el control del checked o unchecked
var flag = false;
//query selector para agregarle el evento onClick al div
$('#drb').on('click', function(event){
  if ( flag == false){
    flag = true;
    //sobreescribo el contenido de la etiqueta div
    $('#drb').html('<input type="radio" checked>');
    //escondo el párrafo con id 'texto'
    $('#texto').hide();
  }else{
    flag = false;
    //sobreescribo el contenido de la etiqueta div
    $('#drb').html("<input type='radio'>");
    //muestro el párrafo con id 'texto'
    $('#texto').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drb"><input type="radio"></div>

<p id="texto">texto a esconder</p>
```

Para la parte del `local storage`  tomando el segundo ejemplo el código de `javascript` quedaría de la siguiente forma

```js
//Se valida si el navegador soporta Local Storage
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){

    //la misma variable para llevar el control del checked o unchecked
    var flag = false;

    //se guarda la variable flag en el local storage
    localStorage.setItem('checked',flag);

    //query selector para agregarle el evento onClick al div
    $('#drb').on('click', function(event){
        if ( flag == false){
            flag = true;

            //sobreescribo el contenido de la etiqueta div
            $('#drb').html('<input type="radio" checked>');

            //escondo el párrafo con id 'texto'
            $('#texto').hide();

            //se guarda la variable flag en el local storage
            localStorage.setItem('checked',flag);
        }else{
            flag = false;

            //sobreescribo el contenido de la etiqueta div
            $('#drb').html("<input type='radio'>");

            //muestro el párrafo con id 'texto'
            $('#texto').show();

            //se guarda la variable flag en el local storage
            localStorage.setItem('checked',flag);
        }
    });
}else{
    alert("Tu navegador no soporta Local Storage");
}
```

Comment: Genial, El segundo ejemplo parece ser certero pero no logró hacerlo funcionar con localStorage para guardar el estado

Comment: ¿Que es lo que quieres guardar en el el local storage? esa parte no me queda muy clara

Comment: El estado del input, si quedo marcado o no al refrescar la pagina. se puede conversar directamente por algún medio?. Gracias..

Comment: Stack Overflow tiene un chat. Dame un momento y te agrego la parte del local storage con el segundo ejemplo que es lo que buscas ¿No?

Comment: Debe haber algún error en el código de javascript para la parte de localStorage, no guarda el estado del input.

Comment: ¿Guardando el estado del imput? yo estoy guardando el valor de la variable **flag**. ¿Cómo lo estás guardando tu?